# How to prevent WSL from caching requests

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker, caching

I have a a Windows 11 system with Ubuntu 22.04 installed on WSL2. I am using docker to develop my project.

I have stumbled upon a problem where the requests going into docker containers are being cached by something inside the WSL. So it seems a page is being cached once I start up the container and open a page in the browser, but when I turn the container off - I still see the page. I have to restart the entire WSL to see anything I have done to the website/docker configuration.

Any idea why this is? I tried for a few hours to look up what can be the issue, chatGPT suggest setting `cache-size=0` in network manager (to prevent internal DNS from doing any caching), but then when I ask it where to set it up it says that it should work fine regardless and does not give me the answer.

I am not sure what is needed to check what is wrong, I will happily update this question with any data that is needed to solve this issue.

This has nothing to do with browser cache - I already checked that.

Comment: Check if the port stays open after stopping the container